# Create a function that checks whether an array has two opposite elements or not for less than n^2 complexity. (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory

Create a function that checks whether an array has two opposite elements or not for less than n^2 complexity. Let's work with numbers.

Obviously the easiest way would be:

```
bool opposite(int* arr, int n) // n - array length
{
 for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  { 
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
     {
       if(arr[i] == - arr[j])
          return true;
     }
  }

  return false;
}
```

I would like to ask if any of you guys can think of an algorithm that has a complexity less than n^2.
My first idea was the following:
1) sort array ( algorithm with worst case complexity: n.log(n) )
2) create two new arrays, filled with negative and positive numbers from the original array
( so far we've got -> n.log(n) + n + n = n.log(n))
3) ... compare somehow the two new arrays to determine if they have opposite numbers

I'm not pretty sure my ideas are correct, but I'm opened to suggestions.

Comment: Sort elements on their absolute values, then scan the result ?  This will, if my head scratching is correct, find *an* instance if it exists, but not every pair of opposites.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark For this decision problem, an instance is sufficient

Comment: sort, then walk (smartly) from both directions to detect opposites.

Comment: or just use a hashtable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important alternative solution is as follows. Sort the array. Create two pointers, one initially pointing to the front (smallest), one initially pointing to the back (largest). If the sum of the two pointed-to elements is zero, you're done. If it is larger than zero, then decrement the back pointer. If it is smaller than zero, then increment the front pointer. Continue until the two pointers meet.

This solution is often the one people are looking for; often they'll explicitly rule out hash tables and trees by saying you only have O(1) extra space.

Comment: I always forget the great use of pointers in C++, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and check to see if the opposite of the number already exist in the set.  if not insert it into the set and check the next element.

```
std::vector<int> foo = {-10,12,13,14,10,-20,5,6,7,20,30,1,2,3,4,9,-30};
std::unordered_set<int> res;
for (auto e : foo)
{
    if(res.count(-e) > 0)
        std::cout << -e << " already exist\n";
    else 
        res.insert(e);
}
```

Output:

```
opposite of 10 alrready exist
opposite of 20 alrready exist
opposite of -30 alrready exist
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33c265a5511deafd)</kbd>

Comment: you're almost there, but you don't need absolute value. actually, it's just creating problems.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath How is it causing problems?  The code does work.

Comment: How could it possibly cause problems? It's not doing much. *Think*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath OKay I figured it out.  It would report that the opposite of 10 already exits if the vector had {10,10} in it.  Thanks for calling me out on it

Answer (score 0):

Let's see that you can simply add all of elements to the `unordered_set` and when you are adding `x` check if you are in this set `-x`. The complexity of this solution is O(n). (as @Hurkyl said, thanks)

**UPDATE**: Second idea is: Sort the elements and then for all of the elements check (using binary search algorithm) if the opposite element exists.

Comment: Use `unordered_set` and you get it down to `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in O(n log n) with a Red Black tree.

```
t := empty tree
for each e in A[1..n]
    if (-e) is in t:
        return true
    insert e into t
return false
```

In C++, you wouldn't implement a Red Black tree for this purpose however. You'd use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), because it guarantees O(log n) search and insertion.

```
std::set<int> s;
for (auto e : A) {
    if (s.count(-e) > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    s.insert(e);
}
return false;
```

---

As Hurkyl mentioned, you could do better by just using `std::unordered_set`, which is a hashtable. This gives you O(1) search and insertion in the average case, but O(n) for both operations in the worst case. The total complexity of the solution in the average case would be O(n).

Comment: Or use `unordered_set` for `O(1)` search and insertion.

Comment: @Hurkyl Fair enough. Though I'm not sure if it's important to care about the worst case O(N) complexity for insertion and search in `unordered_set`.